# ¿Qué quiere decir "Arrastrando tas sí las miradas de todos, y los mozos se formian aquella noche mas tarde"?

Tags: traducción

Estoy leyendo "Nada menos que todo un hombre" y encuentro la oración:

> Arrastrando tas sí las miradas de todos, y los mozos se formian aquella noche mas tarde.

No puedo comprender lo que significa. Traté de usar un traductor y preguntar a mis compañeros, pero nadie en la clase puede comprenderla.

Comment: [Encontré el texto](https://archive.org/stream/nadamenosquetodo00unamuoft/nadamenosquetodo00unamuoft_djvu.txt). Tal y como comenta Abraham, dice _dormían_.

Comment: "Arrastrando **tras de sí** las miradas···"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siguiendo el enlace de fedorqui, el texto parece ser el siguiente:

> La fama de la hermosura de Julia estaba esparcida por toda la comarca que ceñía a la vieja ciudad de Renada; era Julia algo así como su belleza oficial [...]. Los viejos se entristecían al verla pasar, arrastrando tras de sí las miradas de todos, y los mozos se dormían aquella noche más tarde.

Por un lado, los viejos se quedaban mirando a Julia al verla pasar ("arrastraba tras de sí sus miradas", como si Julia tuviera un poder de atracción sobre los ojos de los viejos, que no podían evitar mirarla). Y por otro los jóvenes ("mozos") se quedaban pensando en ella al irse a la cama, y por eso se dormían más tarde.

Posiblemente el problema sea un error en la transcripción que estás leyendo, pero explico las frases por si acaso tenías alguna duda más.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Tiene sentido para mi ahora.

Answer (score 1):

¿Puede ser una errata, y en vez de "**formían** ser "**dormían**"? En ese caso sería el pretérito imperfecto del verbo [**dormir**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=E9e9ZKl). ¿Tiene eso sentido en el contexto?